# With rails/angular on heroku, Is it possible to set different BASE_URL ENV vars in production and staging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, environment-variables

I did set them manually in config, and they show up as different in console.

However, the production code seems to be redirecting to staging.

I assume this is because of how heroku just dumps the existing code from staging to production when I click "promote" from my pipeline?

Any other suggestions?

EDITED

I am actually accessing that variable in the old Angular frontend. Maybe that's the issue? Precompiling assets?

I see a couple of related ("duplicate") answers... which don't quite work for me. They are node.js related, whereas my question is rails + angularjs.  (They do give me some other ideas to explore)

Comment: Sure, it should work out of the box. Unless you're talking about front-end code like React, where that variable gets baked in at build time. But you've only tagged Ruby on Rails.

Comment: The question seems a bit unclear. You can set environment variables in heroku and reference them as environment variables in your code.

Comment: Well, good point. It's Rails and Angular, and I'm trying to access the ENV variable in javascript... Which may bring its own issues.